# How would I edit an attribute of a component of a game object within Unity through a C# file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a script that will dynamically change the near clip plane's distance based on how close the camera is to "nodes" that I place down. The only issue is that I am not sure how to refer to the near clip plane field on the camera component in the C# script in order to change it during runtime. [Image of the camera component for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU6LA.png)

Also, here is the script so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NodeManager : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

    List<Transform> nodeArray = new List<Transform>;
    var parentNode = transform;

    Transform[] children = GetComponentsOnChildren<Transform>();

    foreach (Transform child in children)
    {

        nodeArray.Add(child);

    }

    List<float> distanceMagnitudes = new List<float>;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
    for(var i = 0; i < parentNode.childCount; i++)
    {

        Vector3 offset = nodeArray[i].position - this.position;

        distanceMagnitudes[i] = offset.sqrMagnitude;


    }

    float distanceToClosest = sqrt(distanceMagnitudes.min());

    if(distanceToClosest < 10)
    {

        parentNode.Find("Camera Offset").Find("Main Camera").


    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try not to use `Find("Main Camera")` to get camera in your scene instead define the camera before and set it's value in the `Start()` method like this or make it public and set it in the inspector

```
Camera mainCamera;

private void Start()
{
    // find by type if you will only have one camera always
    mainCamera = FindObjectOfType<Camera>();
    
    // find by tag if you might have several cameras
    mainCamera = GameObject.FindWithTag("Your Camera Tag").GetComponent<Camera>();
}
```

You can get the near clip wherever by..

```
mainCamera.nearClipPlane = 1.0f;  //Your Value
```